# Variable not working outside method

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, parse-platform

I am trying to access some DB results with Node/Express.js on Parse.com because I have some additional data to loop next. Basically I need the Navigation table to loop, and then inside that loop I will loop another table. Is this the proper way? I cannot access the variable `navigation` outside of method below:

```
var Navigation = Parse.Object.extend('Navigation');
var navigation;
var query = new Parse.Query(Navigation);
query.ascending('SortOrder');
query.find().then(function(results) {
    navigation = results
}, function() {
    res.send(500, 'Failed loading navigation');
});

res.render('index', { nav: navigation });
```

Thoughts? I am basically building a mobile single page app. I don't really need routes. But I want to loop through and build the navigation. And also loop through and build the other DIV's which will be shown/hidden according to what the user selects from the navigation. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As currently written, `navigation` is being assigned a value during a callback from an async function...AFTER it is passed to the renderer. At the time that `render` is called, `navigation` has been declared, but not yet given a value.

Any time you assign a value as part of an async callback, every operation that you wish to make use of that value has to either be part of the callback or happen after it (for instance, in a subsequent chained `.then()`)

In this case, you can move your `render` call into the callback and that should be sufficient.

Comment: Yes. It appears that the '.then()' is super crucial to continuing to the next step.

Comment: Absolutely. I /strongly/ recommend reading up on deferreds and promises before getting too deep into using them; there are some subtleties.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `res.render` is called before the callback from `query.find`. Try Moving `res.render('index', { nav: navigation });` inside of `query.find().then(function(results) {
    navigation = results
}`

Comment: Oh I see. But then how do I do additional queries? Getting the navigation is just the beginning. But I get what you're saying about the execution timing. Just wondering about additional queries to build the page up.